# How do I say "the other person"?

Tags: pronouns

I want to write a small dialogue. 
How do I say "**the other person** says/answers etc."?

Then, one said...and **the other** replied...

When names are available I usually use those to indicate who says what, but when there are no names available, what do you do?

Comment: Try looking for this: http://ejje.weblio.jp/content/%E4%BB%96%E4%BA%BA. It seems said as "他人".

Comment: ^ 「[他人]{たにん}」て・・・。　**the** other person ですよ？　others とか another person とかじゃないですよ？？

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How do I say "the other person says/answers etc."?

**もう一人の人**が 言い/答え ました is the common way of saying it.
In polite language it should be もう一人の方{かた}が おっしゃいました／言われました etc.